# how to use convert and datepart at the same time

Tags: sql-server

I have here a select command which is used in my crystal report:

```
SELECT     cfvgl.v_id, operator.o_id, cfvgl.cfvgl_no, operator.owner_name, 
                      operator.business_address, vessel_details.ship_name, payment.or_number , 
                      payment .date_paid , payment.amount , signature.data, 
                      cfvgl.cfvgl_date_released, DATEPART(day, cfvgl.cfvgl_validity_start) as day_issued, 
                      DATEPART(month, cfvgl.cfvgl_validity_start) as month_issued, 
                      DATEPART(year, cfvgl.cfvgl_validity_start) as year,
                      gear.bag_bunt_mesh_size, gear.body_mesh_size, gear.wing_mesh_size,
                      cfvgl.catcher_type, cfvgl.other_gear, gear.stretched_depth, 
                      gear.finished_depth, gear.mesh_size, gear.finished_length, 
                      gear.finished_width, gear.total_length, gear.cod_end_mesh_size,
                      gear.otter_board_size, gear.towing_rope_length, gear.tomweight, 
                      gear.bouyline_length, gear.branchline_length, gear.branchline_distance, 
                      gear.hook_number, gear.hook_type, gear.hook_size, gear.bait_type, 
                      gear.hook_total_number, gear.target_species, gear.mainline_length, 
                      gear.swivel_size, gear.wire_leader_length, gear.netting_type
FROM         cfvgl  INNER JOIN
                      vessel_details ON vessel_details.v_id = cfvgl.v_id INNER JOIN
                      operator ON vessel_details.o_id = operator.o_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      applications ON vessel_details.v_id = applications.v_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      payment ON payment.app_no = applications.app_no LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      gear ON gear.v_id = vessel_details.v_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      signature ON signature.signature_id = cfvgl.signature_id
```

my problem is , i have to convert and display the return date of the datepart(month) as words, for example 1 = january ..

i only datepart the month ,

```
DATEPART(month, cfvgl.cfvgl_validity_start) as month_issued
```

how will i able to change the format of the datepart month to words?

thanks.

Comment: select DATENAME(month,getdate()).Also you can use formula incrystal report to do so .

Answer (score 1):

Use [DATENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) to get the name.

```
DATENAME(month, cfvgl.cfvgl_validity_start) as month_issued
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DATENAME` function to get the month in words like so:

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, cfvgl.cfvgl_validity_start) AS month_issued
FROM yourtable
```